# Getting Index out of range when using onDelete

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

When I'm trying to delete an item in list I'm getting the following error:

*Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range
2021-05-07 09:59:38.171277+0200 Section[4462:220358] Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range*

I have been searching for a solution but none of the once I'v found seems to work on my code.

FIY this is my first app in SwiftUI or Swift for that matter so I'm totally new to this.

So if someone could help me out and explain what I need to change and why I would be so grateful :)

Here is some code I hope will help get to the bottom of the problem.

My model:

```
//
//  Item.swift
//  Section
//
//  Created by Niklas Peterson on 2021-03-11.
//

import Foundation

struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}

extension Item {
    static func getAll() -> [Item] {
        let key = UserDefaults.Keys.items.rawValue
        guard let items: [Item] = UserDefaults.appGroup.getArray(forKey: key) else {
            let items: [Item] = [.section1]
            UserDefaults.appGroup.setArray(items, forKey: key)
            return items
        }
        return items
    }

    static let section1: Item = {
        return Item(name: "Section")
    }()
}

extension Item {
    static func fromId(_ id: String) -> Item? {
        getAll().first { $0.id == id }
    }
}
```

UserDefaults:

```
//
//  UserDefaults+Ext.swift
//  Section
//
//  Created by Niklas Peterson on 2021-03-11.
//

import Foundation

extension UserDefaults {
    static let appGroup = UserDefaults(suiteName: "************ hidden ;) ")!
}

extension UserDefaults {
    enum Keys: String {
        case items
    }
}

extension UserDefaults {
    func setArray<Element>(_ array: [Element], forKey key: String) where Element: Encodable {
        let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(array)
        set(data, forKey: key)
    }

    func getArray<Element>(forKey key: String) -> [Element]? where Element: Decodable {
        guard let data = data(forKey: key) else { return nil }
        return try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
    }
}
```

ContentView:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Section
//
//  Created by Niklas Peterson on 2021-03-11.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var items = Item.getAll()
    
    func saveItems() {
        let key = UserDefaults.Keys.items.rawValue
        UserDefaults.appGroup.setArray(items, forKey: key)
    }

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        items.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
        saveItems()
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        saveItems()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    TextField("", text: $items[index].name, onCommit: {
                        saveItems()
                    })
                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.items.insert(Item(name: ""), at: 0)
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        }
                        
                        EditButton()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Sections")
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        } 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @asperi I have read your answers on other questions on this matter before, but I can't seem to get it to work. And don't totally understand what I need to do to make the changes fit my case. 

I just tried this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712572/swiftui-list-ondelete-index-out-of-range but didn't that to work either


I normally only do design, but wanting to learn how to code in SwiftUI :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Note: This is no longer an issue in `iOS15` since `List` now supports `binding`

This certainly seems to be a bug within `SwiftUI` itself.
After research, It found that the problem comes from the `TextField` binding. If you replace the `TextField` with a  simple `Text` View, everything will work correctly. It looks like after deleting an item, the `TextField` binding is trying to access the `deleted` item, and it can not find it which causes a crash.
This article helped me tackle this problem, Check out [SwiftbySundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/)

So to fix the problem, we’re going to have to dive a bit deeper into Swift’s collection APIs in order to make our array indices truly unique.

1. Introduce a custom collection that’ll combine the indices of another collection with the identifiers of the elements that it contains.

```
struct IdentifiableIndices<Base: RandomAccessCollection>
where Base.Element: Identifiable {
    
    typealias Index = Base.Index
    
    struct Element: Identifiable {
        let id: Base.Element.ID
        let rawValue: Index
    }
    
    fileprivate var base: Base
}
```

2. Make our new collection conform to the standard library’s `RandomAccessCollection` protocol,

```
extension IdentifiableIndices: RandomAccessCollection {
    var startIndex: Index { base.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { base.endIndex }
    
    subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        Element(id: base[position].id, rawValue: position)
    }
    
    func index(before index: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(before: index)
    }
    
    func index(after index: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(after: index)
    }
}
```

3. Make it easy to create an `IdentifiableIndices` instance by adding the following computed property to all compatible base collections (that is, ones that support random access, and also contains `Identifiable` elements):

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Element: Identifiable {
    var identifiableIndices: IdentifiableIndices<Self> {
        IdentifiableIndices(base: self)
    }
}
```

4. Finally, let’s also extend SwiftUI’s `ForEach` type with a convenience API that’ll let us iterate over an `IdentifiableIndices` collection without also having to manually access the `rawValue` of each index:

```
extension ForEach where ID == Data.Element.ID,
                        Data.Element: Identifiable,
                        Content: View {
    init<T>(
        _ data: Binding<T>,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T.Index, Binding<T.Element>) -> Content
    ) where Data == IdentifiableIndices<T>, T: MutableCollection {
        self.init(data.wrappedValue.identifiableIndices) { index in
            content(
                index.rawValue,
                Binding(
    get: { data.wrappedValue[index.rawValue] },
    set: { data.wrappedValue[index.rawValue] = $0 }
)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

5. Finally, in your `ContentView`, you can change the `ForEach` into:

```
ForEach($items) { index, item in
    TextField("", text: item.name, onCommit: {
        saveItems()
    })
}
```

The `@Binding` property wrapper lets us declare that one value actually comes from elsewhere, and should be shared in both places. When deleting the `Item` in our list, the array `items` changes rapidly which in my experience causes the issue.
It seems like `SwiftUI` applies some form of caching to the collection bindings that it creates, which can cause an outdated index to be used when subscripting into our underlying `Item` array —  which causes the app to crash with an out-of-bounds error.

Comment: I just tested it and it works!

I had no idea that it was the TextField causing the crash. I have been searching for days and trying all the solutions I have found here on StackOverflow. Thought it was related to the bug with OnDelete on List or ForEach which many ppl have been mentioning.

I'll read threw everything you wrote some more times to try to understand it. And also check the link you posted!

You made my Friday som much better! Thanks you so much!